# Google Play Promo Code for beta app - "the code you entered is invalid"

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing, promotion-code

I'm trying to beta test an Android app using Google Play's beta testers.  But the way they have it set up, beta testers have to PAY for the app!  I read in another post that you can issue promo codes for the app and give those to your beta testers.

However, I'm trying it now with my own phone and when I enter the promo code, I get the error "the code you entered is invalid".  Anyone know why?  I have the number right - I copied/pasted it from an email.  Can you not use promo codes for beta apps after all?  It seems like you should be able to, if you can actually pay money for them.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:  Well, I got this working. It was either just a matter of waiting several hours, or it may be because I went in and retroactively changed the start time of my promotion to a time much earlier than the current time.  It won't let you do that when you make the promotion, but you can go back and edit it.  Originally I set the promotion to start at the current time when I made the promotion.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, as a dev who generated promo codes a few minutes ago, I was confused why they weren't working - looks like I need to wait a few hours :)